# Android Spinner on activity other than starting activity

Tags: java, android, xml, eclipse, android-layout

I'm having a bit of an issue, I'm working on a android app that requires a spinner to update a string to your spinner selection, I have it all working and everything, the problem is that I need the spinner on another activity than the starting activity but when I start the app with a different activity than the one with the spinner and activate the array adapter and listener at the same time I switch views to the one with the spinner, the spinner is empty with no choices. I can't for the life of me figure this out. PS, sorry about the weird variable names I get bored and instead of making a proper name I think of something on the spot and come back and change it later. PPS The name of the content view with the spinner is orderpage and the one I want to have start with the app is activity_main PPPS I cut out some methods I deemed irrelevant so there are some variables not used. I attached my code below:

```
 package com.NIQUOLI.Deliveryapp;
    import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
    import java.util.ArrayList;
    import java.util.List;
    import java.util.Properties;

    import javax.mail.Message;
    import javax.mail.MessagingException;
    import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication;
    import javax.mail.Session;
    import javax.mail.Transport;
    import javax.mail.internet.AddressException;
    import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
    import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;

    import com.NIQUOLI.Deliveryapp.GMailSender;

    import android.R.string;
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.app.AlertDialog;
    import android.content.Context;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.net.ConnectivityManager;
    import android.net.NetworkInfo;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.os.Debug;
    import android.os.StrictMode;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.Menu;
    import android.view.MenuItem;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
    import android.widget.AdapterView;
    import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;
    import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.Spinner;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    public static boolean deeznuts = false;
    public static String storenamestring;
     public static String namesame;
     public static String instructionsame;
     public int choice = 0;
     private Spinner spinner1;
     private Button button = null;
     String[] stores;
     Spinner sp;

         public void cont(View View){
             deeznuts = true;
             setContentView(R.layout.orderpage);
         }

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            setContentView(R.layout.orderpage);
            button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.send_email);
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            sp = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.sp);
            stores = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.stores);
            if (deeznuts = true){
            ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,stores);
            sp.setAdapter(adapter);
            sp.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

                @Override
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                        int arg2, long arg3) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    int index = arg0.getSelectedItemPosition();
                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "You selected"+stores[index], Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                }

                @Override
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                }

            });
            }
        }
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, 
            int pos, long id) {
        parent.getItemAtPosition(pos);
    }

        @Override
        public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
            // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
            getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
            return true;
        }

        @Override
        public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
            // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
            // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
            // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
            int id = item.getItemId();
            if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
                return true;
            }
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }


    }
```

and of course my XML with the s[ommer:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="com.NIQUOLI.Deliveryapp.SendMailTask" >

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="@string/order_page"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />

    <Space
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/name"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:ems="10"
        android:gravity="center_horizontal"
        android:hint="@string/enter_your_name"
        android:inputType="text" >

        <requestFocus />
    </EditText>

    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/sp"
        android:layout_width="388dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/instructions"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="0.34"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="textMultiLine" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/send_email"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:onClick="onClick"
        android:text="@string/send_order" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

On the 6th line of the onCreate method in the first code sample, `if(deeznuts = true)` should be `if(deeznuts == true)`.

Comment: changed it and to my dismay it still isn't working. Thanks for trying though.

Comment: you never call the method `cont`, so deeznuts will never be true, so the adapter will not be set up in the onCreate. Can you change deeznuts to be initialized to true?

Comment: oops, i forgot to include the XML for the activity with the button that activates the spinner scene. that one calls cont. my bad,